# Add timestamp to wsdl SignedParts node in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

We want to add a value which is different for every request (like timestamp) to be added to `<sp:SignedParts>` in our wsdl under WCF.
Currently wsdl for our service contains:

```
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
 <wsp:All>
   <sp:SignedParts>
    <sp:Body/>
    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
   </sp:SignedParts>
   <sp:EncryptedParts>
    <sp:Body/>
   </sp:EncryptedParts>
  </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

And config for service and binding:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="IService">
 <host>
  <baseAddresses>
   <add baseAddress="https://localhost/Service" />
  </baseAddresses>
 </host>
 <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateBinding" contract="IService" />
 <endpoint binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" address="mex" />
</service>
[...]
<customBinding>
 <binding name="CertificateBinding">
  <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="true" sslProtocols="Tls12" />
   <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" 
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12"
                requireSignatureConfirmation="true"
                enableUnsecuredResponse="false"
                includeTimestamp="true" />
   <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"/>
 </binding>
</customBinding>
```

We know that for complicated requests `<sp:Body/>` will be always different, but what about parameterless body like calling a method GetNextScript?

After some googling I found that it can be achieved by custom `EndpointBehavior` which changes `OutgoingSignatureParts`. For some reason, this approach did not changed wsdl for me.

It is correct approach or there is a simpler way to add a timestamp to `<sp:SignedParts>` node in wsdl?